# Search button that displays the Item from SqliteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I am not experienced with android, i only started learning it

Problem: I would like when i type the name of the item in the Edit Text that it displays the items name, cost, quantity etc. I don't know if i have to use a button so when i click it, the fields of item that i typed in the edit text comes up or if there is a different way to display the fields for the item.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ShoppingList.db";


    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "list_table";


    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";


    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";


    public static final String COL_3 = "COST";
    public static final String COL_4 = "QUANTITY";
    public static final String COL_5 = "PURCHASED";
    public static double total;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +
                " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,COST TEXT, QUANTITY INTEGER,PURCHASED TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String cost, String quantity, String purchased) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, cost);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, purchased);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

This is my xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editSearch"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/search"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

This is my Search Class. I don't have really anything because i don't know what to exactly do

```
public class SearchItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_item);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search List");

    }

}
```

Comment: write a function in `DatabaseHelper ` to retrieve data based on your filter from  DB. use that function to search items in DB.

Comment: refer this  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15323786/6127411

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.

Firstly create instance of your DatabaseHelper class in your activity like as below.

```
public class SearchItem extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_item);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search List");

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(SearchItem.this);

  }
}
```

After doing this create method type of Cursor which returns Cursor in DatabaseHelper class to get the value according to your required sql query as given below.

```
public Cursor getValues_Raw(String selectQuery) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cv = null;
        try {

            cv = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();            
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
        return cv;
    }
```

Now create method in your activity to get the data using Cursor method and call this method from your button click with the data entered in your edittext. If you want to search cost according to name then create method as below

```
    public void getSearchValueAccordingName(String name){
    String selectQuery = "";
    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where "+DatabaseHelper.COL_2+ " = " +name;
    Cursor cur = mDbHelper.getValues_Raw(selectQuery);
String cost = "";

    try {
        if (!(cur == null)) {
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        cost = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_3));
                    } while (cur.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            cur.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

// You can do other thing with your got value. I am showing the toast for demo

Toast.makeText(SearchItem.this, cost, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Call the method getSearchValueAccordingName from your button's clicklistner and here you get your desired value. In Button's click listner do as below.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = edittext.getText();
getSearchValueAccordingName(name)
            }
        });
```

Finally your Activity Class looks like as below.

```
public class SearchItem extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText editText;
    Button button;

    DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_item);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search List");

        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(SearchItem.this);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSearch);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                getSearchValueAccordingName(name);
            }
        });
    }

    public void getSearchValueAccordingName(String name){
        String selectQuery = "";
        selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where "+DatabaseHelper.COL_2+ " = " +name;
        Cursor cur = mDbHelper.getValues_Raw(selectQuery);
        String cost = "";

        try {
            if (!(cur == null)) {
                if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            cost = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_3));
                        } while (cur.moveToNext());
                    }
                }

                cur.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // You can do other thing with your got value. I am showing the toast for demo

        Toast.makeText(SearchItem.this, cost, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it saids getSearchValueAccordingName is never used

Comment: where do i put this?

Comment: for String name = edittext.getText(); , it's just giving me an edit text to use

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me with another problem?, Is it possible to email you?

Comment: nothing comes up in the toast when i click the button

Comment: when i click the button, i want the item name, cost, quantity, if purchased or not to come up in a box or a message box

Comment: For that you must have the data in your database according to that data

Comment: ohh, and how do i achieve this?

Comment: Please refer a link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/